# what is proper way to update(add or remove elements) global numpy array between multiple class?

Tags: python, class

i have this example code.

```
np_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) # declare global numpy array

class A: # declare a class
    def __init__(self, np_arr):
        self.np_arr = np_arr

obj1 = A(np_arr=np_arr) # Create object1
obj2 = A(np_arr=np_arr) # Create object2

np_arr = np.append(np_arr,8) # update global numpy array

print(obj1.np_arr) # check reflect changes in object1
print(obj2.np_arr) # check reflect changes in object1
```

in above example code, i have created one global numpy array then create one class and creates its two object by passing same global numpy array. after that i update that numpy array by adding one more element and after that i print both array form class object. but in this example, value is not getting updated in both class instances. however, when i change existing element value and then print both array form class object. it works.

so my question is what is proper way to update(add or remove elements) numpy array in this situation to get reflation of changes in multiple class object shared numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1):

`np.append` creates a copy of the array when called, so when you call it you are creating a new array and assigning it to the global reference `np_arr`, but not updating the reference in your objects.

You can create a static class variable, which will be the same for all objects of a given class like this:

```
class A: # declare a class
    np_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) # declare class numpy array
    def __init__(self):
        pass

obj1 = A()
obj2 = A()

A.np_arr = np.append(A.np_arr, 8)

print(obj1.np_arr) # check reflect changes in object1
print(obj2.np_arr) # check reflect changes in object2
```